# How to convert a non-time text value into proper time

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

My spreadsheet has time values as shown:
:15
:00:23
:47:15

Excel does not see those as actual time values, but instead returns their values as text. Therefore, math functions will not work because Excel does not see them as numbers.
How do I convert these values to proper numbers, and can this be done without using VBA?

Comment: What are those example time values supposed to represent? Are they all just missing leading zeroes? Or, are they ~randomly malformed?

Comment: The are malformed from an exported .CSV. They are supposed to be time values listed in a column with other time values which are properly formed. However, when performing math functions on them, Excel doesnt recognize them as time values, so errors are returned. Example: 1:30:00 is 0.0625 when converted to text, but :30:00 is just returned as ":30:00". So in essence, they are missing leading zeros, but not always so as shown in the :00:23 example.

Comment: Right - I need to know *exactly* how they are being malformed, and if that mode of malformation is consistent for all malformed values. Are they just missing a leading zero, indicating 'zero hours'?  Or, I guess, it looks like some might be missing both hours and minutes?

Comment: In particular, is that ":00:23" supposed to be 23 seconds past midnight, or 23 minutes past midnight?

Comment: In that example, the ":00:23" is supposed to be a value of 23 seconds, where all the maximum value would be 1:00:00, which Excel sees as 1:00 AM <for whatever reason>. So yes, they are missing leading zeros.

Comment: Understood.  Yep, doable without VBA. Answer in a minute. To confirm, is ":15" supposed to be 15 seconds past midnight?

Comment: Not specifically 15 seconds past midnight, just 15 seconds. All the values are supposed to be time values; such as hh:mm:ss:00

Comment: Ahhk. More or less the same thing, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A properly constructed, nested set of `IF` statements should handle this:*

[image: Excel snip]

*Here's the formula:*

```
=IF(LEFT(C7,1)=":",IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",C7,2)),TIMEVALUE("0:0"&C7),TIMEVALUE("0"&C7)),C7)
```

*How it works:*

- The outer conditional, `IF(LEFT(C7,1)=":",...)`, takes advantage of the fact that all of the malformed values lead with a colon.

  - If the first character isn't a colon, then the value is fine just to be reported as-is: `C7`
  - If the first character *is* a colon, then control is passed to the inner conditional.
- As noted, the inner conditional, `IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",C7,2),...)` is only activated if a colon is in fact found as the first character. It then tries to find a colon in the rest of the string.  Per the [behavior](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c60b7416-e472-4311-a4bd-e01d1aea0ac3) of the `FIND` function, if no colon is found, a `#VALUE!` error is returned, and detected by `ISERROR`
- If `FIND` returns an error, both the zero-hour and the zero-minute numbers must be prepended to the string: `"0:0"&C7`
- If `FIND` returns a number, then another colon is present and only the zero-hour number must be prepended: `"0"&C7`
- `TIMEVALUE` is used in all cases to ensure the time value string is actually interpreted as a time value.

Comment: You sir, are a credit to your knowledge. Much appreciation!  Now can this formula be nested within a VLOOKUP? ;)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to plop the whole thing into any other formula where you need it. It will get unwieldy if you need to use the same value in more than one place; in that case, I would consider adding a helper cell or column to assist with the `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Then the only problem here would be correct syntax (which Im unfamiliar with), since the current formula I use is: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B32,filename.csv!$A:$Q,4,FALSE),"")` Since the formula you referenced includes demonstrated Cell Values and VLOOKUP does a cell match with a specific column.

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` problem is outside the scope of this question. Please post a new question to get help resolving it.  (I don't have time to help further now; you'll get faster help by creating a new question.)  Also, if indeed my answer dealt with the problem of the malformed times, I'd be most appreciative to have my answer marked as The Answer™. :-)

Comment: One further note to this: if you only want times from `0:00:00` to `1:00:00`, a value entered as `##:##` will be interpreted as `hh:mm`, *not* as `mm:ss`.  Handling this would require some extra finesse, but should be doable.